# Unable to free the value of a pointer (which holds a pointer)

Tags: c, pointers, free

I have a database which stores pointers as data. I want to withdraw this value from the database and free the memory location to which this value(pointer) points.

However the compiler won't allow me to do this with the following error:

> error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ג€˜freeג€™`

since it is sure I'm mistakenly freeing the value of the pointer (but this is exactly what I'm trying to do, since this value is a pointer).

Remove value from database function:

```
int ipv4_ifindex_remove (vrf_ipv4_key_t key)
{
    int ret;
    arp_adj_t *adjP;
    ipv4_ifindex_get_ptr(key, &adjP);
    ret = smallmap_remove(bcm_ipv4_map, &key, sizeof(key));
    if (ret != MAP_OK)
    {
        ftr_trace_err("ipv4_ifindex_remove failed key: (%u:%x)",
                      key.vrf, key.ipv4);
    }
    free(*adjP);       // <--- Compiler won't allow this 
    return (ret);
}


static void ipv4_ifindex_get_ptr(vrf_ipv4_key_t key, arp_adj_t **adjP)
{
  int ret;
  ret = smallmap_get(ipv4_map, &key, sizeof(key), (any_t *)adjP);
  if (ret != MAP_OK)
  {
      ftr_trace_verbose("ipv4_ifindex_get: ifindex not found key: (%u:%x)",
                    key.vrf, key.ipv4);
      CASSERT_MSG(0, "Failed to get data from smallmap");
  }
}
```

Add value to database:

```
int ipv4_ifindex_put(vrf_ipv4_key_t key, arp_adj_t adj)
{
  int ret;
  arp_adj_t *adjP = (arp_adj_t *) calloc(1, sizeof(arp_adj_t));
  if (adjP == NULL)
  {
      CASSERT_MSG(0, "uc_entry_add failed to calloc %d",
                  sizeof(arp_adj_t));
  }
  memcpy(adjP, &adj, sizeof(arp_adj_t));

  ret = smallmap_put(bcm_ipv4_map, &key, sizeof(key), (any_t)(adjP));
  if (ret != MAP_OK)
  {
      ftr_trace_err("bcmdb_ipv4_ifindex_put: failed key: (%u:%x)", 
                    key.vrf, key.ipv4);
  }
  return (ret);
}
```

How can I free the pointer without compiler errors?

Comment: "since this value is a pointer" - didn't we [just go through this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873486/free-a-de-referenced-pointer-value-which-is-a-pointer)?  `arp_adj_t` doesn't seem to be a pointer type.

Comment: Thanks, you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the pointer itself to the `free()`, not the value pointed to by the pointer. It really does not matter what does the pointer points to. In this regard, (as long as the pointer was earlier returned by a memory allocator function), the type of the pointee (*?*), does not matter.

At first look, it may seem confusing that you are passing the address of the pointer to the called function (`ipv4_ifindex_get_ptr(key, &adjP);`), but that is because, the memory allocation happens from the called function. As we know, function arguments are passed using call-by-value in C, in case the called function is responsible for allocating memory and the argument in the caller should be able to reflect the memory, you'll be needing a *pointer-to-that* type.

Provided, a pointer returned by the memory allocator function is stored into the pointer variable, you just need to pass the pointer itself to `free()` (*and get done with it*).